# Elements of probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am new to probability and combinatorics and although I find the field fascinating and interesting, I have difficulty in determining the right elements for computing the probability of certain events, I know for instance that if we had 6 red balls and 6 green balls(all enumerated), and if we were randomly picking a pair of those balls, the probability of having 3 pairs of red balls only would be calculated by the following formulae:  (6!/((2!)^3 3!)^2 / (12!/((2!)^6 6!) 
I do not however know for sure how would one find the probability of picking other variations, such as pairs of one red and one green ball, or 2 pairs of one green and one red ball and the remaining pairs being all red and all green.
I would appreciate some insight on how to determine the right formulae to use.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of counting, we use a conditioning argument. Let's look at the more complicated of your two problems, $3$ pairs, of which two are mixed and one is double red. If we are picking in order (which makes no difference to the probability), the double red can occur in three places. We find for example the probability of mixed then double red then mixed.

The probability the first pair is mixed is $2\cdot \frac{6}{12}\cdot \frac{6}{11}$. Call this $a$. Given we got a mixed pair, the probability that the next pair is double red is $\frac{5}{10}\cdot \frac{4}{9}$. Call this $b$. And given this has happened, the probability the next pair is mixed is $2\cdot\frac{3}{8}\cdot \frac{5}{7}$. Call this $c$. Then the probability of mixed then double red then mixed is $abc$.

By the way, it turns out that the other two possibilities also each have probability $abc$, so our probability is $3abc$.